# Error Ganache: Run out of gas - Works in Remix/Not from dApp

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, gas-limit, ganache

I am working on an application that stores and retrieves personal data on/from the ethereum blockchain. Just working on this to improve my Solidity and SC expertise and get comfortable with the environment.

Situation:
I am using remix to code my Solidity contracts. I run a ganache-cli on localhost that functions as the private eth blockchain. Using node.js/express, I have build an application that is hosted on localhost at a different address. There is one particular function that creates a profile, taking in 6 parameters (of which 5 strings). Executing this function from within Remix works fine, executing this function from the dApp sends a "run out of gas error". If I set a function that only takes 3/6 parameters, it works like it should; if I add one more the "run out gas"-error shows up.

I have tried manually setting the gas limit of the ganache-cli to something high (24 million) and done the same when deploying it using Remix. Still, I can't get it to work.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the issue here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set gas for the transaction?

Starting ganache-cli you pass the block gas limit which is the maximum a transaction can use.

But libraries like web3.js has a default of 90k gas, to use more you have to explicitely set the gas in the transaction.

Comment: Yes, I actually did set it using -l flag. Did not seem to change anything. I ended up running it on Rinkeby using MetaMask and no problems occurred strange.

Comment: Passing the -l flag will set the block gas limit, but you can set the gas limit for the transaction passing an extra parameter: `myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe', gas: 1000000})`. Some libraries like web3.js has a default parameter of 90k which might not be enough.

Comment: Neat! Good to know. Will check out that functionality. In the end I deployed it on Rinkeby and used metamask and everything worked. It was some inherit problem with ganache I think.